# ConTeXt t-vim module : add custom keywords

Tags: context, t-vim

I am using the t-vim module to create Python code blocks. It is generally working well, but I'd like to add some specific behavior to represent console output. For example, in the following code :

```
\startpython
  x, y, z = 1, 1, 2
  x == y
  [Out] True
  x == z
  [Out] False
\stoppython
```

I'd like the lines starting with `[Out]` to have [Out] colored and the following not colored. Is it possible, and if yes, how ?

Thank you in advance,

======== EDIT ========

The solution suggested by DG' is almost perfect, and I really like the idea of doing something similar to IPython. However, in my environment the highlithing is still present in the "Out" lines.
Moreover, since I am doing these eye candy setups, I'd like to add the Errors too. I tried to adapt the code but it doesn't seem to work, maybe because I am very ignorant about regexps. I show below a mwe and the output.

```
\startvimrc[name=py_extras]
  syn match InProc /^In\s*\[.*\]:/
  syn match OutProc /^Out\s*\[.*\]:/
  syn match ErrProc /^.*Error:/
\stopvimrc

\startcolorscheme[pscolor]
  \definesyntaxgroup
    [InProc]
    [color=darkgreen]
  \definesyntaxgroup
    [OutProc]
    [color=darkred]
  \definesyntaxgroup
    [ErrProc]
    [color=darkred]
\stopcolorscheme

\definevimtyping[python][
  syntax=python,
  extras=py_extras]

\starttext
\startpython
  In [1]: x, y, z, t = 2, 1, "a", True
  In [2]: x == y
  Out[1]: False
  In [3]: x + z
  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
\stoppython
\stoptext
```

[image]

In this image I'd like no syntax highlighting in the "Out" and "Error" lines, plus every "*Error:" in darkred even if it is an already defined keyword.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 2):

You can add `[Out]` to the keyword list in a vimrc-file for that purpose. It is defined in the `\startvimrc` block and loaded in `\definevimtyping` with `extras=`:

```
\usemodule[vim]

\startvimrc[name=py_extras]
  syn match OutProc /^\[Out\]/
\stopvimrc

\startcolorscheme[pscolor]
  \definesyntaxgroup
    [OutProc]
    [color=darkred]
\stopcolorscheme

\definevimtyping
  [python]
  [syntax=python,
   extras=py_extras]

\starttext

\startpython
x, y, z = 1, 1, 2
x == y
[Out] True
x == z  
[Out] False
\stoppython

\stoptext
```

[image]

You can also use slightly more complicated patterns to mimic the appearance of `ipython`:

```
\usemodule[vim]

\startvimrc[name=py_extras]
  syn match InProc /^In\s*\[.*\]:/
  syn match OutProc /^Out\s*\[.*\]:/
\stopvimrc

\startcolorscheme[pscolor]
  \definesyntaxgroup
    [InProc]
    [color=darkgreen]
  \definesyntaxgroup
    [OutProc]
    [color=darkred]
\stopcolorscheme

\definevimtyping
  [python]
  [syntax=python,
   extras=py_extras]

\starttext

\startpython
In [1]: x, y, z = 1, 1, 2

In [2]: x == y
Out[2]: True

In [3]: x == z
Out[3]: False
\stoppython

\stoptext
```

[image]

Any further and more complicated formatting questions come down to writing a custom vim syntax file, which is best addressed on [vi.stackexchange.com](https://vi.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Note that you can use any name instead of `PreProc`. For example, it could have been called `OutProc` and you then simply need to define a syntax group with the same name using `\definesyntaxgroup`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Aditya – I changed the example according to your suggestion. Btw: Your filter module is really wonderful!

Comment: It is almost perfect : in my environment, it  does not stop the highlighting of "False" after Out, for example. I'll edit the post.

Comment: @A.Licari – The  "False" is highlighted, because it is a keyword it is also a different color.

Comment: @DG' - I understand that it is a keyword, and I'd like it to remain so on the "In" lines ; the point is, is it possible to de-activate keywords on these specific lines that start with "Out" or "*Error" ?

Comment: @A.Licari – The general idea is to write a regular expression that captures the text and assign `black`. Cf. http://www.vimregex.com

Comment: Ok, I'll try a bit with the link you gave me. I may ask for some help, since I'm an Emacs user and not really good with regexps.

Comment: Ok, aaaand nobody is really good with regexes: https://xkcd.com/1171/

Comment: Thanks for XKCD,  but I clearly have problems (not 99 though ^^) 
I have no idea how to "capture" some text (I suppose it must be between ^ and $, but I don't understand much more than that) and "assign" anything to it, even with your link. The only thing I have corrected so far is the Error regexp, and it does not override the already existing Errors highlighting.

Comment: @A.Licari – I think this is as far, as we can go on TeX.SE. Writing vim syntax files is definitely out of scope here and you should head over to https://vi.stackexchange.com and ask there how to get the desired formatting

Comment: @A.Licari: Effectively what you need is a vim syntax scheme which understands python's REPL output. It is not too difficult to do so, once you understand vim syntax highlighting rules.

Comment: @Aditya : While I was working on this, I saw that the Conditionnals (if, elif, else) weren't highlighted. Reading your t-vim.tex and the vimout files, I saw a incompatibility : the vimout highlights them as "Conditional" while the highlighting is defined in t-vim.tex as "Condition". I thought you'd be interested to know that, maybe there is something to fix here (I added a custom "Conditionnal" behavior as a workaround).

Comment: @A. Licari: Thanks for catching that. I uploaded a new release of t-vim which fixes this bug.